Silicone ice cube scum, what is it?
I recently purchased some cheap silicone ice cube trays from Aliexpress. After the first use, I noticed a fatty residue floating on top of my drink. Research suggested it might be lime scale or minerals from hard water. Many websites claim it's calcium sulfate. However, my preliminary tests contradict this theory.
Experimental Evidence

Control Test: I used a plastic ice cube tray with the same water, and no residue appeared.
Vinegar Test: Adding vinegar to an ice cube didn't dissolve the residue.
Hot soap wash: Boiling the ice cube trays in water with dish detergent did not fix the problem. Its unlikely to be the release agent that is ending up in my drink.

Hypothesis
I believe the residue is more likely caused by a silicone additive leaching into the ice cubes. I also noticed a white film forming on the outside of the ice cube tray which feels waxy when rubbed between the finger tips. Can mineral pass through a thick layer of silicone?
Request for Help
Chemists, please help! What tests can I conduct to identify the source of this residue? Are there any specific chemicals I can use to determine the composition of the residue?



You bought a product from ali express and you're willing to put food in it? Solution - dump in trash and buy something from a reputable source where food safety might actually be tested and enforced. Or drink your contaminated icewater if you like that sort of thing.

Unfortunately that is what I will be doing. The problem with Aliexpress is that you cannot get extra information from the seller. I also wouldn't trust their responses without an actual test result from a laboratory. I should add that people buying silicone ice cube trays from reputable shops also have this issue . Everything comes from china these days. Our distibutors and shops do not do any additional testing on these imported products.I think the best thing to do is stay away from silicone ice cube trays. I have now bought stainless steel trays and will use the silicone trays for painting.

never buy anything you put into a wall socket or your body on ali.
